# why doesn't %CD% work after using pushd to a UNC path?

Tags: windows, batch

in a batch file, I'm iterating through a list of unc paths in a file, using pushd to change the context to that location, then executing a command.
%CD% gives the location of the previous directory, not the currently pushed directory.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (filesharelist.txt) do (
 pushd %%A
 echo CD=%CD% - expecting x:\ or x:\subpath here, but get previous directory
 REM xcopy *.xml %DestinationDirectory% /V /C /Y /Z
 popd
)
```

How do I get the current directory?

Comment: Does the user context the script runs as have access (share and file permissions) to the UNC resource(s)?  If you replace your %CD% line(s) with something like `echo test >> test.txt` after the pushd, is test.txt created where you expect?  What I'm getting at is that %CD% might be working fine, but PushD is failing for some reason.

Comment: techie007: dead wrong.

Comment: @techie007 - yes, pushd is working as expected. I tested with DIR >> log.txt as well as CD >> log.txt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%CD%` works like it should. Your problem is that it is expanded *before* your `for` loop even runs. Use delayed expansion instead:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (filesharelist.txt) do (
 pushd %%A
 echo CD=!CD!
 REM xcopy *.xml %DestinationDirectory% /V /C /Y /Z
 popd
)
```

Variable expansion in `cmd` is a little counterintuitive. Normal environment variables (of the `%foo%` form, including pseudo-variables like `%date%`, `%cd%`, ...) are expanded when a statement is *parsed*, not when it's executed. Blocks like the one following the `do` count as a single statement so every variable in the block is replaced by its value *before* the `for` loop even runs. Which means `%CD%` gets replaced by the value it had *before* the loop. Unsurprisingly, this is the value *before* the `pushd`.

Delayed expansion gets around the issue by expanding variables right before a statement is *executed*. They need to use the `!foo!` form for that, though *and* it has to be explicitly activated with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or `cmd` has to be started with `cmd /v:on` or it has to be enabled in the registry. The safest way is the first because it doesn't depend on any outside configuration or environment.

**Bonus quiz:** *Why does* `%DestinationDirectory%` *still work as intended?*

Comment: doh. didn't even think to try delayed expansion. Thanks for the gentle reminder. %DestinationDirectory% works because it's not based on either %%A or anything inside the FOR block. It's defined at the top of the batch file :)

Comment: +1, this saved me from pulling out all of my hair today. DOS = :(

Comment: @DominicP: This has nothing at all to do with DOS ...

Comment: Ha ha, yeah, as soon as I wrote that I figured someone would call me on it. How about: shell scripting in Windows makes me sad?

Comment: @DominicP: Then use PowerShell; after that shell scripting on Unix makes you sad ;)